# Looking for ways to delete the current line and a line before and after and replace the curent line

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I thought of using the shell script and do it, later found sed is an efficient way of doing it. I planned to go with delete line before and after search patterned line and then replace the searched pattern line

So used the following command to delete the line before and after. however, it deletes the line before and the current line

```
sed '$!N;/'perr\(\"pp'/!P;1d;D
```

any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can find the previous and the next line, using `grep -1`, maybe this helps?

Comment: Try `sed -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -e 's/[[:punct:][:alnum:][:blank:]]*\n[[:punct:][:alnum:][:blank:]]*perr("pp[[:punct:][:alnum:][:blank:]]*\n[[:punct:][:alnum:][:blank:]]*/NEW LINE CONTENTS/g' file > newfile` ([demo](https://ideone.com/yvKxch))

Comment: this worked like a magic . thank you . Although I have been on linux from many years, never thought of using sed for the complex cases this before. I am getting familiarized with sed now. I did not find from my googling about the explanation complex sed commands and Can you share sed tutorial for the naive. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file has Unix newlines (\n), please try the following:

```
sed '
:a
N
$!ba    # slurp whole lines in the pattern space
s/\(\n\)[^\n]*\nperr("pp[^\n]*\n[^\n]*/\1REPLACEMENT/g
' file
```

where `file` looks like:

```
aaa
bbb
perr("pp..
ccc
ddd
```

and the output:

```
aaa
REPLACEMENT
ddd
```

Please modify the matching string and the replacement according to
your requirements.